# Install OS X on replaced blank SSD in iMac

Tags: macos, imac, ssd

I have a 2009 27 inch iMac and hard drive died. I have a new 750 GB SSD drive for the iMac. How do I get OS X installed? i have no backup or installation  discs.

Comment: Welcome to apple.stackexchange.com! Before posting a question search for an appropriate q&a – probably a dozen similar questions & answers already exist here! This is neither a forum nor reddit/apple!

Answer (score 1):

The 2009 iMac does not support Internet Recovery, so you'll not be able to download and install Mac OS X directly from the iMac without any external installation medium.

You'll to acquire the installation DVD, insert it into the drive and power on the Mac while holding down the C key on the keyboard.

If you have another Mac, you could possibly download the installation DMG from the App Store and burn it to a DVD or transfer to a USB drive for the iMac.

Another option would be to request the installation discs in an Apple Store - if they still have a supported OS for sale.

A third option is to use eBay or similar to purchase a used installation disc.